# Cakephp and DateTimePicker format

Tags: jquery, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with the format when displaying date.

I use jquery DateTimePicker (http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

In the form I have

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp">
    <?php
        echo $form->input('date',array('type' => 'text','div' => false, 'label' => 'Date'));
    ?>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

with form data which contains date, while script is

```
<script>
    $('#dp').datetimepicker({
    format: 'd MM yyyy',
        autoclose: 1,
        forceParse: 1,
        todayBtn: 1,
        minView: 2
    });
</script>
```

Form date has the format "yyyy-mm-dd" and it is displayed in the date field "date" in that format, ie "2013-03-25" instead of "25 March 2013" regardless of the format defined in the script.

In the other case, when the user picks up the date by using picker, displayed format in the date field is correct, according to definition in the script ('d MM yyyy').

Second problem arises from the fact that expected submitted date format should be "yyyy-mm-dd", and above code produces date in  the format "d MM yyyy".

I tried mirror field,

```
$this->request->data['OSSS']['date_display'] = $this->request->data['OSSS']['date'];
echo $form->input('date_display',array('type' => 'text','div' => false, 'label' => 'Date'));
```

in the html, and in the script

```
linkField = 'OSSSdate';
linkFormat = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
```

and then submitted date is in the correct format, but still remains the problem with the form date format and display format.

Anybody has the idea how to format form date when displaying in the datetimepicker?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you got yours to work. But this works for me...

```
<div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-append date controls" id="dp">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('created',array('type' => 'text','div' => false, 'label' => false, 'wrapInput' => false));?>

        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then

```
$('#dp').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss',  //format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss' either one works     
    language: 'en',
    pick12HourFormat: true
  });
```

This works for me, my 'created' field is a datetime field. MySQL 5.5