# Cakephp 2.x and DatePicker - date format reverts on error to mysql format

Tags: jquery, date, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Folks, rehashing a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346210/cakephp-and-datetimepicker-format/20348867#20348867)..

I'm using Cakephp 2.4.2 and [eternicode's jquery Bootstrap-Datepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

In the `add.ctp` view I have the following code for the date field:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Model.issue_date', array(
'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'error', 'after'),
'fieldset' => false,
'label' => false,
'before' => '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Issue Date</label><div class="col-sm-10">',
'after' => '</div>',
'class' => 'form-control datepicker',
'type' => 'text',
'div' => 'form-group',
    'error' => array(
        'attributes' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div', 'class' => 'alert alert-danger'
        )
    )
)
);
```

Which produces:

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Issue Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input name="data[Model][issue_date]" dateFormat="dmy" class="form-control datepicker" type="text" id="ModelIssueDate" required="required"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the bottom of the view file I have added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

//-->
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        orientation: "bottom right",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
});
</script>
```

I have two problems:

1. After submitting the form, if there is a validation error, and the page refreshes (to display the errors), the date format in the input field reverts back to `yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s` format (I am adding a date to a datetime field used for other purposes, but even when I update the date format for the field in mysql the date format still reverts to `yyyy-mm-dd` on error). The user then has to re-select the date from the datepicker to avoid encountering an(other) error.
2. When I add datetime validation to the field in the /Model/Model.php file, I get a format validation error. Here's the code I use to validate the format (one of many permutations used in both the controller and model to test between dmy, ymd, ddmmyyyy, yyyymmdd format):

   ```
   'issue_date'=> array(
       'allowEmpty' => array(
           'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
           'message'  => 'Please enter a date and time'
       ),
       'format' => array(
           'rule' => array('datetime', 'dmy'),
           'message'  => 'Please enter a valid date'
       )
   ),
   ```

When I remove the date format validation, the form posts fine, and the (correct) datetime is committed to the database.

I've also tried adding the following strtotime in the controller without resolving the issue:

```
if (isset($this->request->data['Model']['issue_date'])) {
    $this->request->data['Model']['issue_date'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($this->request->data['Model']['issue_date']));
}
```

I've also looked in to using the [DateBehavior provided in the bakery with no success](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rikkin/2012/01/26/dateformatter) - it formats the dates correctly in views, but problems 1 and 2 still exist.

Any advice, or if anyone has working examples of using datepicker in cakephp 2.x with `dd/mm/yyyy` format date fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution, or it might be a hack - keen to get confirmation or advice..

At the bottom of the add function of the ModelController.php, I've added the following code to check if the request data for the date field exists (when the page errors, the post data is being returned in the request data), and if it does to format it in the format I'm working with. It's doing the job, but I'd like to work out how I can make this a bit more generic as I have a few date fields throughout my project.

```
//On load or refresh of the add view, check if request data is set for date fields, then format the output in to specific date format
if (isset($this->request->data['Model']['issue_date'])) {
    $this->request->data['Model']['issue_date'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($this->request->data['Model']['issue_date']));
}
```

I've used the same snippet on my edit function also (successfully), so that when a user goes to edit the record, the date is rendered in the input field in the correct format.